# Some WiiWare titles will not play nor move from the SD card

Tags: nintendo-wii, wiiware

I downloaded some WiiWare titles, and they worked just fine directly on the Wii. When I started running out of room, I moved some of these titles to a 2 gigabyte SD card. Upon trying to play them from the SD card, several of the titles produce the `Failed to load.` error.

Upon further manipulation, I now know that even if I have room on my Wii, I can't even move the channels back so that I can play them on the Wii directly.

Did these titles become corrupt over transfer, or will they simply not work from the SD card? Should I format my card in something other than FAT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At a guess, there's not enough room for the game to be copied back to the system.

The Nintendo Wii's SD card support works by copying the game back to the system storage before running it.  Then, when you're finished with the game/program, it deletes it again.

This works differently on the 3DS or WiiU where the game is run directly from the SD card.